# syncronizing search parameters of multiple queries in ms access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

Using data tables from Onetonline.org, I created an ms access db. For each of 7 tables, I created individual queries. Here is the SQL from one of those queries:

> SELECT Knowledge.[Element Name] FROM Knowledge INNER JOIN [Occupation
> Data] ON Knowledge.[O*NET-SOC Code] = [Occupation Data].[O*NET-SOC
> Code] WHERE ((([Occupation Data].[O*NET-SOC Code])="29-2011.02") AND
> ((Knowledge.[Scale ID])="LV") AND ((Knowledge.[Data Value])>3));

BLUF:

I would like to create a simple method (probably using some type of form) where I can update the "29-2011.02" criteria in each query simultaneously. Currently I have to do this one query at a time. The end game is to create a single report using the information from the queries to create job descriptions I can use to post on websites such as indeed, or others. I have created the report for the 29-2011.02 position, but the company has many positions that need similar JD's.
The SOC code would ideally be searchable by Name. I used the code field for convenience at the time of creation.

Comment: Parameter query won't work?

Comment: Agree. Use dynamic parameter in query. Advise not to use popup input prompt. Reference control on form for user input. This is basic Access functionality.